# Is it possible to use Indirect with Minifs?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have the following Formula which works perfectly with one sheet reference.

```
=IF($D9="","",
IF($D9="L",MINIFS(ALL!$A:$A,ALL!$A:$A,">="&$AF9,ALL!$D:$D,"<="&AI9),
IF($D9="S",MINIFS(ALL!$A:$A,ALL!$A:$A,">="&$AF9,ALL!$C:$C,">="&AI9))))
```

Is it possible to have a dynamic sheet reference based on the data in column C?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can use INDIRECT.

For Example, assume your sheet name is in `C19`:

The basic reference would be: `INDIRECT("'"&C19&"'!$A:$A")`

So:

```
=IF($D9="","",
IF($D9="L",MINIFS(INDIRECT("'"&C19&"'!$A:$A"),INDIRECT("'"&C19&"'!$A:$A"),">="&$AF9,INDIRECT("'"&C19&"'!$AD:$D"),"<="&AI9),
IF($D9="S",MINIFS(INDIRECT("'"&C19&"'!$A:$A"),INDIRECT("'"&C19&"'!$A:$A"),">="&$AF9,INDIRECT("'"&C19&"'!$C:$C"),">="&AI9))))
```

Note:

INDIRECT makes the whole formula Voltile.  Volatile function will recalculate every time something in Excel changes.  Which, depending on the frequency of use, may slow down the experience for the user.

Comment: Great.  Thats perfect thanks.

Comment: @Simon if this answered your question, please consider marking as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.

Comment: Done.  Thanks again.  Super Helpful.  And now I know how to Rate and mark correct. :)